# Rewrite file with hardcoded variables in UNIX SHell

Tags: shell, unix

I have properties file (myDataflow.properties) that is called upon as an argument (--override) in a UNIX Shell script - see below.

```
source ./myShell.properties

$DR_HOME/bin/dr -cp $CP_PLUGIN -Xmx64g --engine parallelism=1 --runjson $WORKFLOW_DIR/myDataflow.dr --overridefile myDataflow.properties >> $LOG_FILE
```

Unfortunately the program that is being called upon here must have variables in the properties file hardcoded. I however would like to be able to use variables from my "myShell.properties" file or environment variables within the "myDataflow.properties" file, so that I can easily move my script to new environments.

For example the myDataflow.properties file sets the following variable:

```
DATAFLOW.url=jdbc:ingres://someserver01.local:VW7/mydb
```

However I would like to use a variable called "MYDBURL" read in from myShell.properties instead so that myDataflow.properties file would look like this:

```
DATAFLOW.url=$MYDBURL
```

As I cannot get around the fact that this DATAFLOW.url variable must be hardcoded, I am looking for a way to read the myDataflow.properties file with non hardcoded variables, and write it out to a new file that does have hardcoded variables - which are set using the myShell.properties file. I could then call upon this new file when trying to run myDataflow.dr.

I hope that all makes sense. Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea is to read myDataflow.properties line by line, make the replacements, and write out the replaced line. Right?

Let's assume that the shell variable `current_line` holds one original line from the property file to be expanded. You could then use

```
eval 'echo $current_line' >>hardcodedDataflow.properties
```

This solution applies to sh/bash/ksh. If you are happy with running your shell script under Zsh, you can do it even simpler:

```
echo ${(e)current_line} >>hardcodedDataflow.properties
```

Comment: So tried so I tried this based on your suggestion: 

`source ./myShell.properties

input="./myDataflow.properties"
while IFS= read -r current_line
do
  eval 'echo $current_line' >> ./hardcodedDataflow.properties
done < "$input"

echo "$(cat ./hardcodedDataflow.properties)"
echo $MYDBURL` 

Looking at the output, none of the lines that use $MYDBURL have evaluted, however my echo of $MYDBURL shows that it has been set. Can you think of any reason for this not evaluating?

Comment: Okay - this does work, but you have to put the eval statement in double not single quotes. Thus `eval "echo $current_line" >>hardcodedDataflow.properties` If you use double quotes within the imported properties file (in my case myDataflow.properties), these must be escaped with a "\". Thanks for your help on this user1934428!

Comment: Ah, you are right. Alternatively, you can write it without quotes, i.e. `eval echo $current_line`. Still, I prefer the Zsh solution, because it is safer. `eval` is always a bit risky.